# Node.js hangs when trying to determine if all images have been loaded

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise, puppeteer

I am writing a script with Puppeteer in which I need to determine if all images have finished loading even if they failed to load, here is the problematic part:

```
var images = await page.evaluate(function() {

    return new Promise(
        function(resolve, reject) {
            var imgs = document.images,
                imagesNumber = imgs.length,
                counter = 0;

            if (imagesNumber == 0)
            {
                resolve({images: []});
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++)
            {
                imgs[i].addEventListener( 'load', incrementCounter, false );
                imgs[i].addEventListener( 'error', incrementCounter, false );
            }

            function incrementCounter() {
                counter++;

                if ( counter === imagesNumber ) {
                    resolve({images: imgs});
                }
            }
        }
    )
});
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but nodejs just hangs at this code. Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "hangs"?  Do you just mean that your promise doesn't resolve?  Or do you mean that the process is actually stuck in an infinite loop?

Comment: Nodejs process doesn't finish it just stays ON, when I remove the above code the rest of the app works

Comment: So, the promise just never resolves?  Then, you need to add a bunch of debugging to see what the image count is at, which images haven't given you a `load` message and then and only then can you start to figure out why.  This is basic debugging.  We can't do this for you because we don't have access to the relevant code and document.

Comment: How do I log message from the promise?

Comment: I tried passing the nodejs console to the evaluation function but I get "Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: cons.log is not a function"

Comment: ‘console.log(...)’

Comment: You can add a timeout that resolves with the `counter` value after some time to see what the value is. In addition, you can resolve with an array containing the file names of the images and whether it fired or not to find out which image is the problem.

Comment: @Geert-Jan I passed it in as 'cons' so it is correct

Comment: @ThomasDondorf problem is I can't console log out ...

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that some of the images are already loaded, when you run the `page.evaluate`.

To check whether an image is already loaded, you can use the attribute `complete`:

```
            for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++)
            {
                if (imgs[i].complete) {
                    counter += 1;
                }
                imgs[i].addEventListener( 'load', incrementCounter, false );
                imgs[i].addEventListener( 'error', incrementCounter, false );
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to debug which images are loading and which ones are not.  You can instrument your code like this to output the total number of images and the status of each image number as it completes.  That should leave you with a list of images that completed in the console and you can then see which ones did not.

```
var images = await page.evaluate(function() {

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var imgs = document.images,
            imagesNumber = imgs.length,
            counter = 0;

        if (imagesNumber === 0) {
            resolve({images: []});
        }

        console.log(`Total images: ${imgs.length}`);
        for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
            if (imgs[i].complete) {
                console.log(`Image ${i} already complete, counter=${counter}`);
                incrementCounter();
            } else {
                imgs[i].addEventListener( 'load', incrementCounter(i, 'load'), false );
                imgs[i].addEventListener( 'error', incrementCounter(i, 'error'), false );
            }
        }

        function incrementCounter(i, status) {
            return function() {
                console.log(`Image ${i} ${status}, counter=${counter}`)
                counter++;

                if ( counter === imagesNumber ) {
                    console.log("All images loaded");
                    resolve({images: imgs});
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Once you know which images have not completed, you can then examine the HTML to see what additional debugging you might need for those specific images to see what is going on with them.

Comment: console log doesn't work even if I put it at the top of the promise

Comment: @PetarVasilev - I have no idea what that comment means.